# No longer able to send emails via Azure / SendGrid once app is deployed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, razor, sendgrid

Current web app works fine when running in Visual Studio; however, once it's published and you try sending a form on the actual Azure website then it returns an "Internal Server Error". (note: Currently using SendGrid to send emails)

Still pretty new to all of this and while I can set a break point in VS and debug that way to see where the error is occurring I'm not sure how to do the same once it's deployed. I don't know if there is something wrong with the ajax call and it's never making it to the Action Method in my controller or if it is making it there but then messing up something once the IdentityMessage service is called.

Thoughts/suggestions on where it's going wrong at and what could be done to fix it?

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
@*script for someone who presses the send/email button*@ 
    <script>
        $("#sendButton").click(function (e) {
        //var htmlBody = $("#myModal .modal-body").text();
        var toName = $("#toFirstName").val() + " " + $("#toLastName").val();
        var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("DidItWork", "Home", new { toName = "_toName_", toEmail = "_toEmail_", toNameBlank = "_toNameBlank_", Blank1 = "_Blank1_", Blank2 = "_Blank2_", Blank3 = "_Blank3_", Blank4 = "_Blank4_", Blank5 = "_Blank5_", Blank6 = "_Blank6_", Blank7 = "_Blank7_", phoneNumberBlank = "_phoneNumberBlank_", emailBlank = "_emailBlank_", fromNameBlank = "_fromNameBlank_" }))';
        url = url.replace('_toName_', toName);
        url = url.replace('_toEmail_', $("#toEmail").val());
        url = url.replace('_toNameBlank_', $("#toNameBlank").text());
        url = url.replace('_Blank1_', $("#blank1").text());
        url = url.replace('_Blank2_', $("#blank2").text());
        url = url.replace('_Blank3_', $("#blank3").text());
        url = url.replace('_Blank4_', $("#blank4").text());
        url = url.replace('_Blank5_', $("#blank5").text());
        url = url.replace('_Blank6_', $("#blank6").text());
        url = url.replace('_Blank7_', $("#blank7").text());
        url = url.replace('_phoneNumberBlank_', $("#phoneNumber").val());
        url = url.replace('_emailBlank_', $("#fromEmail").val());
        url = url.replace('_fromNameBlank_', $("#fromNameBlank").text());
        console.log(url);
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (result) {
                alert("Success. It worked.");
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                alert("Sorry, there was a problem! Error: " + errorThrown + ". Status: " + status + ". Console: " + xhr);
                console.log("Hello");
                console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
                console.log("Status: " + status);
                console.dir(xhr);
                console.log("Good-bye");
            },
        });
        // return false to cancel the default action and leave the AJAX call
        //return false;
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> DidItWork(string toName, string toEmail, string toNameBlank, string Blank1, string Blank2, string Blank3, string Blank4, string Blank5, string Blank6, string Blank7, string phoneNumberBlank, string emailBlank, string fromNameBlank)
        {
                var manager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = toName, Email = toEmail };
                var bodyHtml = "<p>Dear " + toNameBlank + "</p><p>I am a student at XYZ" + Blank1 + " and I am interested in exploring " + Blank2 + ". I found your contact information at " + Blank3 + " and think you might be helpful because I am " + Blank4 + ".</p><p>Would you be willing to chat " + Blank5 + " sometime " + Blank6 + ", I would really appreciate learning more about " + Blank7 + ".</p><p>I look forward to hearing from you soon. Feel free to reach me at " + phoneNumberBlank + " or " + emailBlank + " with your availability and interest.</p><p>Thank you in advance and have a great week.</p><p>Best,<br />" + fromNameBlank + "</p>";
                var result = await manager.CreateAsync(user, "tempPW123!");
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await manager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "ABC is attempting to reach out to you", bodyHtml);

                    return null;
                }
                return null;
        }
```

**IndentityConfig.cs**

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
    {
        public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            await configSendGridasync(message);
        }

        // Use NuGet to install SendGrid (Basic C# client lib) 
        private async Task configSendGridasync(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            // Create the email object first, then add the properties.
            var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
            myMessage.From = new MailAddress("****@gmail.com", "From Name"); 
            myMessage.AddTo("*****@gmail.com"); //to myself for now, while testing but will replace with the appropriate email address
            myMessage.Subject = message.Subject;
            myMessage.Html = message.Body;
            myMessage.Text = message.Body;

            var username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SENDGRID_USER"];
            var pswd = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SENDGRID_PASS"];

            // Create credentials, specifying your user name and password.
            var credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, pswd);

            // Create an Web transport for sending email.
            var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);

            // Send the email.
            if (transportWeb != null)
            {
                await transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
            }
            else
            {
                await Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Global.asax.cs**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "MyNewRoute",                                              // Route name 
                "Home/DidItWork/{toName}/{toEmail}/{toNameBlank}/{Blank1}/{Blank2}/{Blank3}/{Blank4}/{Blank5}/{Blank6}/{Blank7}/{phoneNumberBlank}/{emailBlank}/{fromNameBlank}",               // URL with parameters 
                //(string toName, string toEmail, string bodyText)
                new { controller = "Home", action = "DidItWork", toName = "", toEmail = "", toNameBlank = "", Blank1 = "", Blank2 = "", Blank3 = "", Blank4 = "", Blank5 = "", Blank6 = "", Blank7 = "", phoneNumberBlank = "", emailBlank = "", fromNameBlank = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
        }
```

**Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/ -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=*********" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-...;Initial Catalog=aspnet-...;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="SENDGRID_USER" value="*******@azure.com" />
    <add key="SENDGRID_PASS" value="*******" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180"
     targetFramework="4.5" />
    <trace enabled="true" pageOutput="true" requestLimit="40" localOnly="false"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="*********" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="*********" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="*********" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="*********" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="*********" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="*********" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="*********" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="*********" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="*********" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="*********" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you please confirm that your username and password are indeed in the `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SENDGRID_USER"];`? Maybe print them to the logs?

Comment: Not completely sure if I'm interpreting what you said correctly but if you're asking if the username and password are in the proper place and being utilized correctly I believe the answer is 'yes' -- the following link is a screenshot that of what it looks like in the SendAsync / IdentityMessage when debugging: http://1drv.ms/1zM9y4q -- is this the type of confirmation you were asking about?